# New Managed Property button is not visible so, i cannot add new managed property and edit old ones?

Tags: search, managed-property, sharepoint-search, crawled-property, search-schema

I want to add a new managed property fropm Search Schema.ç But ther is no button .
In the past, this button was active.
I also can't edit the properties I created before.I can only view.

How do I reactivate the button?

**I marked the place where the button should be in the picture. But this is not currently visible to me.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer by searching the internet.
Mentioned in the link below. It is necessary to pay attention to Url. And I typed the url wrong.

Site Level Schema - only view option is with this URL: /_layouts/15/listmanagedproperties.aspx?level=site

**SiteCollection Level Schema - allows edit is with this URL:** /_layouts/15/listmanagedproperties.aspx?level=sitecol

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/sharepoint-online-unable-to-edit-managed-properties-in-the/m-p/25226